Generate a Access right table from SQL script
I already have several SQL scripts that generate my tables in postgreSQL. Each script alterns  the right access and it grants different access to several tables in different databases. Do you know if there is a tool that imports the script and construct an user/group access right tables? I can use it for documentation and to verify that the rights are correct.
Thanks for the support.
I can always use someting like this
SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, privilege_type
FROM information_schema.table_privileges
WHERE grantee = 'xxx';

but I miss the policies when defined.
